# Long labels for input components in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadin 22 application that features a view that has 2 `Select` fields next to each other. They belong together (are actually dropdowns for month and year) and they require only a single label, which is longer than the component on the left.

I've tried to put it on the left component but then it gets cut off:

[image]
What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you might want to try the [Custom Field](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/custom-field) component for this.

Another alternative is to customize the CSS a bit:

```css
vaadin-select::part(label) {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: I'll go with the CustomField option, I didn't think of it because I'm not interested in using Binder to bind both fields to a single property.